# opencv4nodejs node-gyp build error

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv

При билде библиотеки opencv4nodejs получаю следующие ошибки:

```
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/tracking/tracking.o
In file included from ../cc/tracking/tracking.cc:6:
../cc/tracking/./Trackers/TrackerBoosting.h:8:14: error: no member named 'TrackerBoosting' in namespace 'cv'
        cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerBoosting> tracker;
                ~~~~^
In file included from ../cc/tracking/tracking.cc:7:
../cc/tracking/./Trackers/TrackerMedianFlow.h:8:14: error: no member named 'TrackerMedianFlow' in namespace 'cv'
        cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerMedianFlow> tracker;
                ~~~~^
In file included from ../cc/tracking/tracking.cc:9:
../cc/tracking/./Trackers/TrackerTLD.h:8:14: error: no member named 'TrackerTLD' in namespace 'cv'
        cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerTLD> tracker;
                ~~~~^
In file included from ../cc/tracking/tracking.cc:13:
../cc/tracking/MultiTracker.h:11:70: error: no member named 'MultiTracker' in namespace 'cv'
class MultiTracker : public FF::ObjectWrap<MultiTracker, cv::Ptr<cv::MultiTracker>> {
                                                                 ~~~~^
In file included from ../cc/tracking/tracking.cc:21:
../cc/tracking/./Trackers/TrackerMOSSE.h:10:14: error: no member named 'TrackerMOSSE' in namespace 'cv'
        cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerMOSSE> tracker;
                ~~~~^
5 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/tracking/tracking.o] Error 1
```

Признаюсь, очень плохо понимаю что это значит, но приложу файлы из сообщений сюда.

/cc/tracking/tracking.cc

```
#include "opencv_modules.h"

#ifdef HAVE_OPENCV_TRACKING

#include "tracking.h"
#include "./Trackers/TrackerBoosting.h"
#include "./Trackers/TrackerMedianFlow.h"
#include "./Trackers/TrackerMIL.h"
#include "./Trackers/TrackerTLD.h"

#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 1, 0)
#include "./Trackers/TrackerKCF.h"
#include "MultiTracker.h"
#endif

#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 2, 0)
#include "./Trackers/TrackerGOTURN.h"
#endif

#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 4, 0)
#include "./Trackers/TrackerMOSSE.h"
#endif
#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 4, 1)
#include "./Trackers/TrackerCSRT.h"
#endif

NAN_MODULE_INIT(Tracking::Init) {
    TrackerBoosting::Init(target);
    TrackerMedianFlow::Init(target);
    TrackerMIL::Init(target);
    TrackerTLD::Init(target);

#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 1, 0)
    TrackerKCF::Init(target);
    MultiTracker::Init(target);
    v8::Local<v8::Object> trackerKCFModes = Nan::New<v8::Object>();
    FF_SET_JS_PROP(trackerKCFModes, GRAY, Nan::New<v8::Integer>(cv::TrackerKCF::MODE::GRAY));
    FF_SET_JS_PROP(trackerKCFModes, CN, Nan::New<v8::Integer>(cv::TrackerKCF::MODE::CN));
    FF_SET_JS_PROP(trackerKCFModes, CUSTOM, Nan::New<v8::Integer>(cv::TrackerKCF::MODE::CUSTOM));
    Nan::Set(target,FF::newString("trackerKCFModes"), trackerKCFModes);
#endif

#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 2, 0)
    TrackerGOTURN::Init(target);
#endif

#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 4, 0)
    TrackerMOSSE::Init(target);
#endif
#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 4, 1)
    TrackerCSRT::Init(target);
#endif

};

#endif
```

/cc/tracking/./Trackers/TrackerBoosting.h

```
#include "../Tracker.h"

#ifndef __FF_TRACKERBOOSTING_H__
#define __FF_TRACKERBOOSTING_H__

class TrackerBoosting : public Tracker {
public:
    cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerBoosting> tracker;

  static NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init);
  static NAN_METHOD(New);

    static Nan::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> constructor;

    cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> getTracker() {
        return tracker;
    }
};

#endif
```

/cc/tracking/./Trackers/TrackerMedianFlow.h

```
#include "../Tracker.h"

#ifndef __FF_TRACKERMEDIANFLOW_H__
#define __FF_TRACKERMEDIANFLOW_H__

class TrackerMedianFlow : public Tracker {
public:
    cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerMedianFlow> tracker;

    static NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init);
    static NAN_METHOD(New);

    static Nan::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> constructor;

    cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> getTracker() {
        return tracker;
    }
};

#endif
```

/cc/tracking/./Trackers/TrackerTLD.h

```
#include "../Tracker.h"

#ifndef __FF_TRACKERTLD_H__
#define __FF_TRACKERTLD_H__

class TrackerTLD : public Tracker {
public:
    cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerTLD> tracker;

    static NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init);
    static NAN_METHOD(New);

    static Nan::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> constructor;

    cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> getTracker() {
        return tracker;
    }
};

#endif
```

/cc/tracking/MultiTracker.h

```
#include "macros.h"
#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
#include "Mat.h"
#include "Rect.h"

#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 1, 0)

#ifndef __FF_MULTITRACKER_H__
#define __FF_MULTITRACKER_H__

class MultiTracker : public FF::ObjectWrap<MultiTracker, cv::Ptr<cv::MultiTracker>> {
public:
    static Nan::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> constructor;

    static const char* getClassName() {
        return "MultiTracker";
    }

    static NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init);

    static NAN_METHOD(New);
    static NAN_METHOD(AddMIL);
    static NAN_METHOD(AddBOOSTING);
    static NAN_METHOD(AddMEDIANFLOW);
    static NAN_METHOD(AddTLD);
    static NAN_METHOD(AddKCF);
    static NAN_METHOD(AddMOSSE);
    static NAN_METHOD(AddCSRT);
    static NAN_METHOD(Update);
};

#endif

#endif
```

/cc/tracking/./Trackers/TrackerMOSSE.h

```
#include "../Tracker.h"

#if CV_VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL(3, 4, 0)

#ifndef __FF_TRACKERMOSSE_H__
#define __FF_TRACKERMOSSE_H__

class TrackerMOSSE : public Tracker {
public:
    cv::Ptr<cv::TrackerMOSSE> tracker;

    static NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init);
    static NAN_METHOD(New);

    static Nan::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> constructor;

    cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> getTracker() {
        return tracker;
    }
};

#endif

#endif
```

Операционка: MacOS Big Sur 11.6

Node.js пробовал разные от 10 до последней 17.2.0 (сейчас она)

Python 2.7.16

opencv 4.5.3_3

opencv4nodejs 5.6.0

node-gyp -v v8.4.1

System Darwin 20.6.0

Xcode 13.1
Build version 13A1030d

Готов на созвон в мите с трансляцией экрана дабы вместе решить проблему.

Comment: операционка? версия ноды? версия пайтона? версия opencv4nodejs?

Comment: @nörbörnën 
Как же я вас ждал))) Сори, не указал.
Операционка: MacOS Big Sur 11.6
Node.js пробовал разные от 10 до последней 17.2.0 (сейчас она)
Python 2.7.16
opencv 4.5.3_3
opencv4nodejs 5.6.0

Comment: Лучше напишите версию XCode. Она важнее всего остального.

Comment: Только что проверил. У меня все работает.

Comment: @DiD Xcode 13.1
Build version 13A1030d

Comment: @DiD какая у вас версия opencv?

Comment: opencv 4.5.4 macOS 12.0.1 (21A559) Xcode 13.1 (13A1030d) node 17.2.0

Comment: Я тестировал собрав билд и запустив вот этот проект: https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv-electron

Comment: @DiD могу у вас поинтересоваться каким образом вы собирали билд?

Comment: @Glechik конечно, любые вопросы. NodeJS и Electron у меня уже стояли. Я установил через `brew install opencv@4` сам OpenCV. Далее я указал переменной окружения папку на lib внутри папки с устанрвленной opencv. И просто запустил `electron-rebuild`. В двух словах вот так.

Comment: @DiD хотел бы узнать детальнее по поводу указания переменной окружения папки на lib.
Это в bash-profile или package.json своего node.js проека? Никогда не работал с електроном, но возможно он умеет как-то билдить opencv... Немного запутался и был ба рад любой уточняющей информации, так как меня уже убеждают, что мою ошибку исправит лишь понижение версии opencv 4.5.0...

Comment: Electon позволяет работать с элементами на странице в одном контексте с модулями, подключаемыми через `require()`. Чтобы все модули были доступны без папки `node_modules`, можно использовать `electron-rebuild`, который собирает все зависимости в один архив. У меня есть чистый макбук с архитектурой x86_64. Я повторю установку, постараюсь, записать процесс подробно.

Comment: @DiD Буду очень благодарен. Надеюсь это закроет мой вопрос, а то уже голова кипит. У всех получается, у меня нет. Не знаю куда и смотреть)

Comment: Я попытался поднять на старом маке i7 x86_64 и там opencv не собирается никак. На M1 arm64 все работало без проблем.

Comment: @DiD обновлять мак пока нету возможности)))
Вас понял. В любом случае, спасибо. Если будут еще какие-то варианты - буду рад увидеть))

Comment: Скорее всего они что-то сделали с XCode. Была бы возможность откатиться обратно версию на 9-11, думаю, все бы откомпилировалось на-ура.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повторил все как указано в данном [комменте](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/issues/805#issuecomment-806314329)

Попутно стыкаясь с мелкими ошибками, но все они решаемы. Всем спасибо. Всем удачи.